# Do Bottle & Cappy affect wasteland events?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When I would send people out into the wasteland to explore they would come across locations/events fairly regularly (i.e. Red Rocket).

After getting Bottle & Cappy these events don't seem to trigger anymore.

It's been days and I've typically had around 3-5 dwellers wandering the wasteland without any of these events ever triggering... but Bottle & Cappy come to my vault extremely often (approx. every 20 minutes or so).

Comment: I don't believe so. I don't have any evidence for this, other than personal experience, but random wasteland events do still trigger for me, even after finding Bottle and Cappy. I think it may have more to do with the amount of Quests you send your Dweller on

Comment: You may be correct on that. I've since triggered a couple of Wasteland events, though still nothing in comparison to before.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've read scrounging around the internet, it appears that the answer is **no, Bottle and Cappy *do not* affect wasteland events.**

From [Section 20.9](https://github.com/therabidsquirel/The-Fallout-Shelter-FAQ/wiki/Section-20:-Quests#209) (*How do random quests with explorers work?*) of therabidsquirel's [*The Fallout Shelter FAQ*](https://github.com/therabidsquirel/The-Fallout-Shelter-FAQ/wiki):

> As explorers do their thing they can stumble upon random
> quests...Discovering them is real time and you have to be in-game to
> get the notification, so if you're only checking for short periods of
> time your chances of getting a random quest are fairly low even with a
> lot of explorers.

From [Section 21.2](https://github.com/therabidsquirel/The-Fallout-Shelter-FAQ/wiki/Section-21:-Bottle-and-Cappy#212) (*What do they do when they visit?*) of the same wiki, what Bottle and Cappy *do affect* is as follows:

> Whenever they stop in a room there's a chance they'll start dancing.
> If you tap on them while they're dancing you'll get a reward.
> Cappy...rewards caps when tapped...Bottle...can reward caps or
> Quantums. After a while...they'll leave.
>
> For the duration of their visit they also provide a temporary +20%
> happiness boost to everyone in the vault. If a dweller was higher than
> 80% happiness before the visit (including 100%) they will return to
> exactly what they were before (unlike the small bonus from radio
> rooms).

The Fandom pages for [Bottle](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Bottle) and [Cappy](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Cappy) support the latter and neither make any mention of having any affect on wasteland events.

According to [this](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/fallout-4-nuka-world-characters-come-to-fallout-sh/1100-6443006/) Gamespot article, Bethesda released this statement regarding the Fallout Shelter 1.7 update:

> To celebrate the launch of the Nuka-World add-on for Fallout 4, all
> Fallout Shelter players will receive their first Special Event Quest:
> a Nuka-World-themed mission which, once completed, allows Nuka-World
> mascots Bottle and Cappy to appear in the Vault. Tapping on Bottle and
> Cappy while they visit will reward players with Caps and Nuka-Cola
> Quantum.

From Bethesda's statement, it would appear that Bottle and Cappy were only ever intended to produce a few extra caps and Nuka-Cola Quantum for the player.

[This](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-08-25-fallout-shelter-gets-nuka-world-mascots-in-new-update) Eurogamer article for the same update says more or less the same, as does [this](https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/35541/%7E/how-do-i-get-bottle-and-cappy-in-fallout-shelter%3F) Bethesda Support response and [this](https://mooreviews.com/2018/07/13/fallout-shelter-review/) review's screenshot caption.